# Can z-index be used in javaScript and what is the use of jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a project wherein I want to use z-index and jQuery ,but I don't know how to use them. I am drawing 3D objects on the canvas and I want to select them,non overlapping objects gets selected but both the overlapped objects get's selected when clicked, so I want to use z-index feature in javaScript as I am coding in javaScript.Is jQuery required? as I am also using events.

Comment: jQuery is not required, but you're generally better off using a library.

Comment: You're generally better off NOT using a library. Yes, what is the use of jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use javascript to get or set z-index as

```
yourElement.style.zIndex = 100;
zIndex = yourElement.style.zIndex;
```

jQuery is not required. But if you are already using it in same page then preferably use it.

```
$("#element").css('z-index',100);
zIndex = $("#element").css('z-index');
```

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` is from CSS. Javascript is not required unless you are dynamically changing the `z-index` on some event on the page, such as a page click, then you do not need Javascript.

You do not *necessarily* need jQuery because jQuery *IS* Javascript and anything you can do in jQuery you can do in Javascript. But if you would like to save lots of time, use jQuery and either do `.css('z-index', 2000)` or `.addClass('foo')` where `.foo` is defined in css and has a z-index.